# Dojo FilteringSelect load data

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have the following code below, which will create a **FilteringSelect** and set the first selected item:

```js
// Store initialization:
var jsonStore = custom.store.JsonRest({ ... });
var memoryStore = dojo.store.Memory();
var myStore = dojo.store.Cache( jsonStore, memoryStore);
var dataStore = custom.store.MyObjStore({ objectStore: myStore, ...  });

// FilteringSelect initialization:
var fsel = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
             id: 'fsel',
             searchAttr: 'id',
             store: dataStore
           });

// Setting the first item on FilteringSelect, retrieved from store objects
fsel.store.fetch({ query: {id:""},
  onComplete: function (items, request) {
    var val = "";
    if (items.length>0) val = items[0].id;
    fsel.set('value', val);
  }
});
```

1. First problem is that, if the `items[0].id = 0`, this item is not set on FilteringSelect.
2. `fsel.store.fetch({ ... })` queries the server, which is ok. The problem is that the retrieved items are not kept in memory, or they are, but are not retrieved by FilteringSelect on the next event.
   I mean, when I click the first time on FilteringSelect's dropdown another query is sent to server to get the items, the following times they get from memory.

Could anyone help me to solve these two problems?

Note: I'm using Dojo version 1.7.2 (27913).

Comment: `val = items[0].id[0];` should do it. Store values are presented as arrays.

Comment: Could You please tell us which version of dojo are You using.

Comment: `id` is a property of object, and I'm getting the first item on the store, so `items[0]`.
I forgot to mention the version, I'm using **Dojo 1.7.2 (27913)**.

Comment: I meant that the properties of an store object are arrays. Or at least in 1.6.

Comment: That's not happening here, unfortunately. There should be something related with FilteringSelect widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a talk with someone from dojo, I solved my question the following way:

1. Switching to the last version (**1.8.1**), fixed this first issue.
2. Using the *memoryStore* on FilteringSelect, instead of cache store (*myStore*), will just make use of objects in memory. Making a query on *myStore* (cache store) will load the objects from server to memory.

```js
// Store initialization:
var jsonStore = new JsonRest({ ... });
var memoryStore = new Memory();
var myStore = new Cache(jsonStore, memoryStore);
// Note: ObjectStore was removed.

// FilteringSelect initialization:
var fsel = new FilteringSelect({
         id: 'fsel',
         searchAttr: 'id',
         store: memoryStore
       });

// Setting the first item on FilteringSelect and loading items to memory
when (myStore.query({id:""}),
  function (items, request) {
    var val = "";
    if (items.length>0) val = items[0].id;
    fsel.set('value', val);
  }
);
```